# Retrofit (Android) - Getting An Object Returned From Callback

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Tried searching for this question, but couldn't find it (possibly due to my inexperience with Java/Retrofit).

I get an instance of the ImgurAPI class and call `ImgurAPI::getImage()`:

```
ImgurAPI imgurAPI = ImgurAPI.getInstance();
Image image = ImgurAPI.getImage(someIDHere);
```

I make a request to get an Image, and get a response:

```
public Image getImage(final String id) {
    Image requestedImage = null;

    imgurService.getImage(id, new Callback<Image>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Image image, Response response) {
            //I need to get requestedImage = image to return
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            System.out.println("Failed: " + error.toString());
        }
    });
    return requestedImage;
}
```

The issue I am having is determining a proper way to get the image returned in `success()` back to the Activity that called `ImgurAPI::getImage()`.

Originally I had a global variable in ImgurAPI `Image image`, and I would assign that to the retrieved Image, and thenI would return that: `return ImgurAPI.image;`. It worked, but it felt incorrect.

Does anyone have a recommendation to do this properly? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION**

I was able to do more searching after getting a couple answers, and found this to solve my issue:

```
ImgurAPI imgurAPI = ImgurAPI.getInstance();
imgurAPI.getImage("OhERyMa", new Callback<Image>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Image image, Response response) {
        // Simple test to check for functionality
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String link = image.getData().getLink();
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.imageScrollerLayout);
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
        Picasso.with(context).load(link).into(iv);
        ll.addView(iv);
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        System.out.println(error.toString());
    }
});
```

And `ImgurAPI::getImage()` now contains:

```
public void getImage(final String id, Callback<Image> callback) {
    imgurService.getImage(id, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. The `ImgurService.getImage(...)` method is asynchronous, and you can not (should not) synchronously wait for it to finish. Instead, use the `Callback<Image>` to execute the code you wanted to execute when your method would return the image.

Comment: After reading your recommendation, I was able to do a little more searching with more targeted keywords (thank you). I found an example here: [link](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/235)

I will update my question with the new code, and consider this answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the callback pattern, if you cant use your results directly from from where getImage is defined you can pass a callback into the method to handle the results.

```
public interface ImageLoadedCallback { 
    void onImageLoaded(Image image);
}

public void getImage(final String id, final ImageLoadedCallback callback) {
    Image requestedImage = null;

    imgurService.getImage(id, new Callback<Image>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Image image, Response response) {
           callback.onImageLoaded(image);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            System.out.println("Failed: " + error.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I believe my solution found is this, but with just utilizing the Callback interface that comes with Retrofit. See reply to nhaarman. Thanks!